# Third party fund transfer on Stripe Cloud module for Parse

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments

I want to create recipient on stripe using cloud module on parse. I am able to create customer (e.g. using **Stripe.Customers.create()**) and able to charge customer(**String.Charges.create())** from his credit card. but not able to create a recipient (**Stripe.Recipients.create()**) for transfer the money to his account. This create function for Recipients is not defined .

But this same thing available for Node.js (https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#create_recipient).

any solution for this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it does really not exist for the moment. You could just issue the HTTP request based on their protocol. It should work.
The parameter required you could take from the curl samples:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_recipient

Comment: how to make the http request for stripe? The link uses curl language.

Comment: Thanks, i made a http request to the stripe server.

Comment: @neeraj Did you end up creating an httpRequest to generate a transfer? I can't get mine to work.  It says "Unrecognized request URL (POST: /v1/transfer)".

Comment: Yes @JakeT.. I created the http request object to generate transfer . please follow the link https://stripe.com/docs/api/curl#create_transfer (sorry for the late reply)

Comment: @neeraj I got mine working. I was using an example from their Migrating to Connected Accounts documentation that left out a required parameter (currency), which is included in the link you gave.  Thanks.